# Shell, reading lines with variables and quoted strings

Tags: perl, awk, sed, grep, ksh

I am trying to read variables from a file in ksh.
But some are single words/numbers, others are strings in quotes
Example.

```
Field1a "this is field 2" 3 "And field 4"  
Field1b "2" "field three" 444444
```

I want to allocate variables.
Pass 1.

```
a=Field1a  
b="this is field 2"  
c=3  
d="And field 4"
```

Pass 2

```
a=Field1b   
b="2"  
c="field three"  
d=444444
```

How to do it?
All attempts I have tried split on the space only, or on the " only.
I need a smart mix of both.

Answer (score 0):

it depends what ksh version you're running so idk but heres how to do it in bash:

```
while IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' a b c d; do
    echo "a=$a"
    echo "b=$b"
    echo "c=$c"
    echo "d=$d"
    echo "----"
done < <(awk -v FPAT='[^ ]+|"[^"]+"' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i; printf "\0"}' file)
a=Field1a
b="this is field 2"
c=3
d="And field 4"
----
a=Field1b
b="2"
c="field three"
d=444444
----
```

now read the man page for bash and your ksh version to learn how to do the same (or just use bash). The above uses GNU awk for FPAT.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a csv package. Perl, ruby, python all have solid programs.

Here is a demo in Python:

```
python -c '
import sys
import csv

for line in csv.reader(sys.stdin, delimiter=" "):
   print "\n".join(line)' <<<$(echo 'Field1a "this is field 2" 3 "And field 4"
Field1b "2" "field three" 444444')
```

Prints:

```
Field1a
this is field 2
3
And field 4
Field1b
2
field three
444444
```

Answer (score 0):

You tagged `perl` so a perl solution - use `Text::ParseWords`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::ParseWords;
use Data::Dumper;

while (my $line = <DATA> ) {
  chomp $line; 
  my @fields = quotewords ( ' ', 0, $line );

  print Dumper \@fields;
}

__DATA__
Field1a "this is field 2" 3 "And field 4"
Field1b "2" "field three" 444444
```

Gives

```
$VAR1 = [
          'Field1a',
          'this is field 2',
          '3',
          'And field 4'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          'Field1b',
          '2',
          'field three',
          '444444'
        ];
```

And because perl does pithy:

```
my @stuff = map { chomp; [quotewords ( ' ', 0, $_ )] } <>;
print Dumper \@stuff;
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you split the line on the fields?
A field starts without a quote until the first space (or end-of-line),
or
A field starts with a quote until the next quote (followed by space or end-of-line).

A field is matched with `[^"]*( |$)` or with `"[^"]*"( |$)`.

You can use `sed` for inserting fieldseperators, something unique like `\r` (after dos2unix of a windows file).

```
while IFS=$'\r' read -r a b c d e; do
   echo "a=$a"
   echo "b=$b"
   echo "c=$c"
   echo "d=$d"
   if [ -n "$e" ]; then
      echo "input has more than 4 fields, ignoring $e"
   fi
done < <( sed -r 's/([^"]*|"[^"]*")( |$)/\1\r/g' inputfile)
```